# insertion constraint by Foreign key due to referencing same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table employee which has **ssn** as primary key and another **supr_ssn** attribute which is a foreign key referencing **ssn** of employee table itself. So while inserting into table I get foreign key constraint because I have not inserted any value into **ssn**. Here is my table:

```
create table employee(
    Fname varchar(15) not null,
    Minit char,
    Lname Varchar(15) not null,
    ssn char(9) not null,
    Bdate Date,
    Address varchar(30),
    sex char,
    Salary decimal(10,2),
    super_ssn char(9),
    Dno int not null,
    primary key(ssn),
    foreign key(super_ssn)references employee(ssn),
    foreign key(dno)references department(Dnumber)
)
```

When I do insertion into table, with the code I get foreign key constraint:

```
insert into sample.employee(
    Fname, Minit, Lname, ssn, Bdate,
    Address, sex, salary, Dno
)
values(
    'John', 'B', 'Smith', '123456789', 01/09/1965,
    '731 fondren,housten', 'M', 30000, '333445555', 5
)
```

Comment: I may be asking a stupid question, but shouldn't you make `super_ssn` accept null values, for records that sits on top of the tree ?

Comment: I'm not getting that error in my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/978a7b/1). I had to correct a few problems, though. I took out the `department` foreign key (since there is no department table here) and there is an extra value `5` at the end of the VALUES part of the insert.

Comment: @Bartdude: I believe allowing nulls is the default setting. You have to explicitly say `NOT NULL` to not allow nulls.

Comment: ya its not necessary over here because we will have super_ssn values which are present in ssn. As ssn is primary key it will not have any null values and in turn super_ssn also cannot have null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enter a value to a foreign key if the primary key value doesn't exist.
So, Enter the primary key values then try updating the foreign key value accordingly.